# How to subset a MNIST dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

I am following a tutorial on Generative Adversarial Network for TensorFlow. The tutorial uses an MNIST dataset to train the model. I want to reduce the size of the input so that my program runs faster but have no idea how to get a subset of the MNIST dataset that I am using. Below is the code that I used to extract the data set:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method

```
mnist.next_batch(batchsize)
```

that extracts a random sample of length batchsize from the train set.

If you do not want something random, you can access them by

```
x = mnist.train.images[start_batch:end_batch]
y = mnist.train.labels[start_batch:end_batch]
```

or similar with `mnist.test` for the test set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding so quickly. I am able to subset train.images and train.labels using the method you provided. However, after I subset these datasets, I get an NDArray object and I could not call any method that is designed for mnist dataset for an ndarray. Is there any way I can cast an ndarray back to mnist dataset?